# unable to locate package mesosphere

Tags: apache-zookeeper, scheduler, mesos, marathon, mesosphere

i want to make multi node cluster for mesos for that i have to install mesosphere on master node.so that I am tring to install mesosphere on ubantu 16.4. aftre generating keys and updating repositories when i tried to install mesosphere it gave me an error:
 sudo apt-get install mesosphere

output:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mesosphere

is there any solution for this or any other links or videos through which i can build multinode cluster for mesos/mesosphere.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "Mesosphere" you mean DC/OS.

- It's not possible to install it on Ubuntu, this OS is not supported
  yet, please see the [DC/OS compatibility matrix](https://docs.mesosphere.com/version-policy/#dcos-platform-version-compatibility-matrix).
- You cannot
  install DC/OS using conventional package managers. Please choose one
  of [the supported installation methods.](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.12/installing/)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve multinode HA cluster just with mesos. You dont need mesosphere DC/OS to do that.

Best way i think is to install odd number of mesos masters and zookeeper instances, point that masters to zookeeper to create quorum and create mesos agent instances that points to your zookeeper mesos znode. After that you have HA mesos cluster.

For more information just look at docs: http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/

Mesos configuration for zookeeper can be found here: http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/configuration/master/

Mesosphere provides packages for Ubuntu in their repos: https://mesosphere.com/blog/mesosphere-package-repositories/

For zookeeper follow docs: https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperStarted.html

Zookeeper package can be found in official ubuntu repos.